# MATLAB: How to create a prompt dialog, whose number of inputs depend on the other variable i.e previously obtained?

Tags: matlab, command-prompt, prompt

I read a value 'cases' from the user using prompt.

Depending on this value of 'cases', I want to create another prompt dialog box which again asks for following inputs('Start of <>' and 'End of <>')

Suppose 'cases' = 1;
Then the next prompt dialog should ask for 'Start of Case 1: ' and 'End of Case 1: '

Suppose 'cases' = 2;
Then the next prompt dialog should ask for 'Start of Case 1: ', 'End of Case 1: ','Start of Case 2: ', 'End of Case 2:
 '
Suppose 'cases' = 3;
Then the next prompt dialog should ask for 'Start of Case 1: ', 'End of Case 1: ','Start of Case 2: ', 'End of Case 2:', 'Start of Case 3: 'and 'End of Case 3: '.

and so on.(The order must be the same i.e Start1,End1,Start2,End2 etc)

Can anyone help me about how to create such a prompt dialog box and store the values in a array(whose size depends on the values of 'cases')?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a cell array with length of `2*cases`.
Then use a `for` loop with something like

```
for k=1:cases
  Prmpt{2*k-1} = ['Start of Case' num2str(k) ': ']
  Prmpt{2*k} = ['End of Case' num2str(k) ': ']
end
```

and then to make the dialog:

```
inputdlg(Prmpt)
```